# Why org.hibernate.TransientObjectException during join/select?

Tags: criteria-api

Trying to wrap my head around Criteria API (ouch). I have 3 classes: Devices, Offices, and SiteCodes. all joined

Devices.java

```
private Offices office;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "office_id")
public Offices getOffice() {
    return office;
}

public void setOffice(Offices office) {
    this.office = office;
}
```

Offices.java:

```
private List<SiteCodes> siteCodes;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "site_code_map", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_code_id") })
@OrderBy("siteCode ASC")
public List<SiteCodes> getSiteCodes() {
    return this.siteCodes;
}

public void setSiteCodes(List<SiteCodes> siteCodes) {
    this.siteCodes = siteCodes;
}
```

SiteCodes.java

```
private id;
private String siteCode;
<getters and setters>
```

I'm trying to find Devices.devId using the site code.  The sql would look like this:

```
 SELECT d.dev_id
   FROM devices d, offices o, site_code_map s, site_codes ss
  WHERE d.office_id=o.office_id
    AND s.office_id=o.office_id
    AND s.site_code_id=ss.site_code_id
    AND ss.`site_code`='0S21'
```

I'm trying to use joins, but don't quite get how to do it. I got the following to compile:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Integer> cq = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
Root<Devices> d = cq.from(Devices.class); 
Join<Devices, Offices> join1 = d.join(Devices_.office);
ListJoin<Offices,SiteCodes> join2 = join1.join(Offices_.siteCodes);
```

I couldn't figure how to use join2 so I used join1 and a path like this

```
ParameterExpression<SiteCodes> p = cb.parameter(SiteCodes.class, "sitecode");
Predicate pr = cb.isMember(p, join1.get(Offices_.siteCodes));
cq.where(pr);
```

and eventually

```
TypedQuery<Integer> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
<set parameter here to a SiteCode object>
List<Integer> idList = tq.getResultList();
```

It produces sql like the following. That subquery doesn't belong - I want it to use a join and anyway it throws a TransientObjectException  even though all I'm doing is selecting:

```
select
    devices0_.dev_id as col_0_0_ 
from
    devices devices0_ 
inner join
    offices offices1_ 
        on devices0_.office_id=offices1_.office_id 
inner join
    site_code_map sitecodes2_ 
        on offices1_.office_id=sitecodes2_.office_id 
inner join
    site_codes sitecodes3_ 
        on sitecodes2_.site_code_id=sitecodes3_.site_code_id 
where
    ? in (
       select
            sitecodes4_.site_code_id 
       from
            site_code_map sitecodes4_ 
       where
            offices1_.office_id=sitecodes4_.office_id
```

And anyway it also throws this error (not including whole stack trace unless sopmeone wants to see it):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an 
unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before 
flushing: dne.nmst.dac.model.SiteCodes
```

This confused me because I wasn't doing any saving, just selecting.

How do I get this to work?  I want the criteria constructed properly and of course to not have an error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this worked out. Hope it helps someone else.  Still don't know why I got the error it did, but I figured out the join's and that made the query work correctly

Joins:

```
Root<Devices> d = cq.from(Devices.class); 
Join<Devices, Offices> join1 = d.join(Devices_.office);
ListJoin<Offices,SiteCodes> join2 = join1.join(Offices_.siteCodes);
```

Parameter expression and Predicate:

```
ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class, "sitecode");
Predicate pr = cb.equal(join2.get(SiteCodes_.siteCode),p);
```

Produced SQL like this:

```
select
  devices0_.dev_i a col_0_0 
from
  devices devices0 
inner join
  office offices1 
      o devices0_.office_id=offices1_.office_i 
inner join
  site_code_map sitecodes2 
      o offices1_.office_id=sitecodes2_.office_i 
inner join
  site_code sitecodes3 
      o sitecodes2_.site_code_id=sitecodes3_.site_code_i 
where
  sitecodes3_.site_code=?
```